# Как отсортировать список чисел?

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос, который выводит список чисел number 1, 4, 10, 15.

Можно как-нибудь с помощью функции какой-нибудь сделать так, чтобы выводило не эти числа, а просто 1, 2, 3, 4? Если number содержит например 5 чисел, то выводить, как 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Т.е. если запрос возвращает 4 строчки, то надо, чтобы вместо значений были цифры от 1 до 4? Почему нельзя просто вернуть колво (4 или 5), а потом в PHP это потом использовать?

Comment: Спасибо в принципе да можно... Просто мне было интересно возможность, с точки зрения MySQL... Такой способ, как вы сказали, да рабочий... Я его использовал, но думал можно сразу средствами MySQL одного запроса так... Вот и спросил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без текста самого запроса точный ответ дать не могу, но нужная Вам структура такова:

```
SELECT  @s:=@s+1 as auto_increment,[ВЫВОДИМЫЕ ПОЛЯ ОСНОВНОГО ЗАПРОСА]
FROM    [ОСНОВНОЙ ЗАПРОС],
        (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
```

в поле `auto_increment` будет искомый счетчик